# JavaScript array cross random number？

Tags: javascript, random

In the array randomly take three numbers, but the number of up and down the left and right non-adjacent (array cross random number)

This is my code, how can I optimize (get the number more evenly)?

Thanks~

array

```
var a = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
];

function select() {
    var a = [
        [0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5],
        [6, 7]
    ];

    var lastSelect = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var index = getRandomNumber(lastSelect, a[i].length);
        console.log(a[i][index]);
        lastSelect = index;
    }
}

function getRandomNumber(lastSelect, max) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    if (random == lastSelect) return getRandomNumber(lastSelect, max);
    else return random;
}

select();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a [modulus operator %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.C2.A0.25_%28Modulus%29), that finds the remainder of division.

```js
var a = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5],
    [6, 7]
];
function select() {
  //generating random 0 or 1
  var random = Math.round(Math.random());
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i][(i+random)%2]);// 0 or 1
  }
  console.log("-----------");
}
//test
for(var j=0;j<5;j+=1){
  select();
}
```